# Krusader: How to set up "Escape" key as a shortcut for "Unselect All" action?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, file-manager

In Krusader I would like to unselect all selected files just by pressing the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key. I did set that up in Krusader's configuration, but it does not work. I had to change the key sequence  to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd>, and that works well, but <kbd>Escape</kbd> only would be better.

Any idea how to make it work?